# XML Value to variables

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a perl script that returns XML results, and I'm trying to set those values into variables but I cant even seem to get them separated even with XML::Simple

I tried: 
"print $xml->{"to"}{"from"}{"heading"}{"body"} . "\n";"

to return the XML values with no luck, but what I need to to set them into variables:

1. $to
2. $from
3. $heading
4. $body

Here is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use XML::Simple;

my $xml;

my $XML_Server = "http://videotuber.atwebpages.com/cgi-bin/cgitest.pl";
my $UserContent = get($XML_Server);


print qq~$UserContent \n\n~;


print $xml->{"to"}{"from"}{"heading"}{"body"} . "\n";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There a quite a few things that make it hard for people to help you:

1. You don't include an example of the XML input
2. You don't include an example of the expected output from your code
3. The URL you provide contains something that's not valid XML
4. You're trying to use XML::Simple - nobody recommends that
5. You apparently don't understand Perl references so you've just made up `$xml->{"to"}{"from"}{"heading"}{"body"}` and said it doesn't work

I'd recommend changing the code that generates the URL you're fetching to create valid XML (no blank lines before the `<?xml ...`

I'd also recommend using XML::LibXML instead.  Here's [a tutorial](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/).

And here's some code to get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml_server = "http://videotuber.atwebpages.com/cgi-bin/cgitest.pl";
my $user_content = get($xml_server);

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $user_content);

my $to      = $dom->findvalue('/note/to');
my $from    = $dom->findvalue('/note/from');
my $heading = $dom->findvalue('/note/heading');
my $body    = $dom->findvalue('/note/body');

print "To:      $to\n";
print "From:    $from\n";
print "Heading: $heading\n";
print "Body:    $body\n";
```

**Edit**

For posterity, the XML returned by the quoted URL was returning something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>alice</to>
  <from>bob</from>
  <heading>reminder</heading>
  <body>don't forget the milk</body>
</note>
```

(but with a blank line before the initial XML declaration)

Comment: Grant Thank very much, that's exactly what I needed!